# Limit the minimum size of html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html on a html5 video:

```
<video id="video1" autoplay>
       <source src="static/video/5986637.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

css:

```
video
{
width: 100%    !important;
height: auto   !important;
position:fixed;
}
```

I want to keep the width and height in such css until the height of the video is smaller than a certain value. After smaller than a certain value, the height will remain unchanged while the width will still keep 100%. So what I should do in CSS/Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: You mean like a maximum height? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp or min height: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS min-height for this. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

```
video {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```